# Use Post as Front Page

Tags: posts, frontpage

Is there a way to use a post as the front page?

I'd like to be able to call the latest post from a given custom post type, in a certain custom taxonomy and with a specific term and use this as the front page - similar to using a page as the front page, but using a post instead (showing comments, trackback, etc. too)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You just need to modify the main query:

   ```
   // inside functions.php
   function wpse47667_intercept_main_query( $wp )
   {
       // Modify the main query object
       $wp->query_vars['custom_tax_name'] = 'custom_term_slug';

       return $wp;
   }
   add_filter( 'parse_request', 'wpse47667_intercept_main_query' );
   ```
2. Then you have to replace `the_excerpt()` with `the_content()` inside your `index.php/home.php/front-page.php` template file, to show the full post instead of the excerpt.